# Given an existing jar file and source code, how do I alter the code?

Tags: java, jar

I am working with some java code downloaded from SourceForge. I have the sourcecode, but users are directed to run the code via jar files:

```
java -jar jarfile.jar -i inputfile.txt -o $outputdirectory
```

Naturally, I can see what's inside the `jarfile.jar` with the following command,

```
jar tf jarfile.jar
```

Here is my question: There are a few things I would like to change in the sourcecode, and then run. How do I do this? Do users usually

(1) change the compiled java code in jarfile.jar? That sounds like a mess

(2) wrap the source code into the jar file again?

How would I take the source code (with changes I've made) and create a new `.jar` file?

Comment: Instead of just replacing the compiled class(es) in the jar file, you should look up what build instructions there are and use them to build your own jar file with your changed classes.

Comment: Java code is not "compiled" into the Jar file. If you open the Jar file, its just plain old Java code. You can use (almost) any archive tool (maybe not the inbuilt Windows one, but 7-Zip, for sure) and you'll still be able to see the source code. So, just use an API to extract the source files from the Jar archive, then repackage into an entirely new Jar file.

Comment: JAR = Java Archive

Comment: @mjones.udri Ok, so extract the source files directly from the jar file, change them, and then repackage the jarfile. How does one do this?

Comment: Hang on, I'll write an answer with some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this code [here](https://coderanch.com/t/379312/java/extracting-contents-jar-file) to extract the JAR contents:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.jar.*;
import java.util.zip.ZipException;

public class jara {
    public static void main (String args[])throws IOException,ZipException
    {
       JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("jarfile.jar");
       Enumeration en = jarFile.entries();
       while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
         String ent=proc(en.nextElement());
         if(ent.indexOf("/")>0)
         {
         String fil=ent.substring(0,ent.indexOf("/"));
         System.out.println(fil);
         File local=new File(fil);
         if(!local.exists())
         local.mkdirs();
         }
         if(ent.indexOf(".")>0)
         {
         int n=ent.length();
         String fil1=ent.substring(ent.lastIndexOf("/")+1,n);
         System.out.println(fil1);
          extract(jarFile.getName(),ent);  
         }

        }
     }

       public static String proc(Object obj)
       {
       JarEntry entry = (JarEntry)obj;
       String name = entry.getName();
       System.out.println("\nEntry Name: "+name);
       return(name);
       }

       public static void extract(String jarName,String entryName)throws IOException,ZipException
      {
      JarFile jar = new JarFile(jarName);
          System.out.println(jarName + " opened.");

          try {
             // Get the entry and its input stream.

             JarEntry entry = jar.getJarEntry(entryName);

             // If the entry is not null, extract it. Otherwise, print a 
             // message.

             if (entry != null) {
                // Get an input stream for the entry.

                InputStream entryStream = jar.getInputStream(entry);

                try {
                   // Create the output file (clobbering the file if it exists).

                   FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(entry.getName());

                   try {
                      // Allocate a buffer for reading the entry data.

                      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                      int bytesRead;

                      // Read the entry data and write it to the output file.

                      while ((bytesRead = entryStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                         file.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                      }

                      System.out.println(entry.getName() + " extracted.");
                   }
                   finally {
                      file.close();
                   }
                }
                finally {
                   entryStream.close();
                }
             }
             else {
                System.out.println(entryName + " not found.");
             } // end if
          }
          finally {
             jar.close();
             System.out.println(jarName + " closed.");
          }
       }
     }
```

Then, just read the Java source files as if they were text files, modify them, then write them to new files.

Then to package the jar, you can use [this tutorial](http://javabeat.net/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/), which uses the [Java Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

Comment: Isn't this the same as `jar -xvf myjar.jar`?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Within the above `JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("jarfile.jar")`, I input the name of my jar file. I get the following error: `Error: Could not find or load main class jara.java`

Comment: Are you using the name of the external Jar file instead of `"jarfile.jar"`? `jara` is the name of the class from the example code.

Comment: You should replace "jarfile.jar" with the name of the external jar file. Also, if the jar file is not in the current working directory, you need to specify the path to the jar file, not just the name.